# ¿Se puede agregar más de un valor a un atributo?

Tags: java

Tengo la siguiente clase main:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        InfoDestino inf = new InfoDestino();

        inf.setOrigen("Chihuahua");
        inf.setDestino("Monterrey");
        inf.setNoboletos(5);

        System.out.println("$"+inf.Costos());

        System.out.println("$"+inf.TotalClaseOro(0));
        System.out.println("$"+inf.TotalClasePlata(0));
        System.out.println("$"+inf.TotalClaseBronce(0));


    }

}
```

Y la siguiente clase:

```
public class InfoDestino {

     String origen;
     String destino;
     int noboletos;
     double cantidad;

    public String getOrigen() {
        return origen;
    }
    public void setOrigen(String origen) {
        this.origen = origen;
    }
    public String getDestino() {
        return destino;
    }
    public void setDestino(String destino) {
        this.destino = destino;
    }
    public int getNoboletos() {
        return noboletos;
    }
    public void setNoboletos(int noboletos) {
        this.noboletos = noboletos;
    }

    public double Costos() {
        if(this.origen == "Mexico" && this.destino =="Cuernavaca") {
            this.cantidad = 100;
        }else if (this.origen == "Mexico" && this.destino =="Acapulco") {
            this.cantidad = 400;
        } else if (this.origen == "Cuernavaca" && this.destino =="Mexico") {
            this.cantidad = 100;
        } else if(this.origen == "Cuernavaca" && this.destino =="Acapulco") {
            this.cantidad = 300;
        }else if(this.origen =="Acapulco" && this.destino =="Mexico") {
            this.cantidad = 400;
        }else if(this.origen =="Acapulco" && this.destino =="Cuernavaca") {
            this.cantidad = 300;
        }else if(this.origen == "Tijuana" && this.destino =="Monterrey") {
            this.cantidad = 1289.60;
        }else if(this.origen == "Chihuahua" && this.destino == "Monterrey") {
            this.cantidad = 1009.45;
        }   
        return cantidad;
    }

    public double TotalClaseOro(double TCO) {

        TCO = (this.cantidad*this.noboletos*1.20+384);
        return TCO;
    }

    public double TotalClasePlata(double TCP) {

        TCP = (this.cantidad*this.noboletos*1.15+368);
        return TCP;
    }

    public double TotalClaseBronce(double TCB) {

        TCB = (this.cantidad*this.noboletos*1.10+352);
        return TCB;
    }

}
```

El objetivo de este programa es sacar el costo dependiendo del origen y del destino, tal y como se ven las condiciones en el metodo Costos.

Pero como podría agregar otro dato en el atributo sin quitar el que ya tengo?, es decir, nuevos calculos.

Comment: ¿qué quieres lograr con esto?

Comment: @jachguate que se impriman los nuevos valores

Comment: Para imprimir nuevos valores no tienes por qué almacenar en otro atributo. Calcula una vez con el atributo que tienes e imprimes. Luego haces otro calculo, si quieres utilizando o no el mismo atributo, e imprimes. El resultado se logra.